# Regex - replace if between tag and contains substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace a string using regex if the string is between `[]`s and contains `{someText}`

Ex:

```
testText[ This text : {TestProperty}] other text
```

to:

```
testText other text
```

Comment: What help do you need, how far did you get with your own attempts? How did those attempts fail, or break, and in what way? It's worth noting that both "*I want*" and "*I need*" are not questions, and we're not here to write your code, or do your work, for you; we're here to help. Please: read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what you want to replace. Please give more details if the answer does not satisfy you
Replace this :
`\[(?=[^\]]*{TestProperty})[^\]]*\]`
By nothing
Note that this will not work if there is any `]` inside your `[]`
See javascript demo below :

```js
var str = "testText[ This text : {TestProperty}] other text";
console.log("Input : "+str);
str = str.replace(/\[(?=[^\]]*{TestProperty})[^\]]*\]/g, '');

console.log("Output : "+str);
```

Comment: @MickelBernier: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do : pass over a json object and replace some fields tagged like this {Property} in text with value of property. If i tag like this [Test : {Property} $] if val of property is null or empty just replace all inside [ ] to ''

Comment: @MickelBernier: Sorry, I am really trying to understand you, but I can't... Could you providemore examples ? Like what you have at the beginning, then what you want to have at the end ?

Comment: @MickelBernier: Please, could you edit your question to add your code ? Because I can't read that ;)

Comment: @MickelBernier: Do you understand what I am saying ? Sorry, I won't be able to help you until you do more efforts. Like I said : examples, code *in the question*, not in comments, more explanations about what you want to do. And read the comment of David Thomas below your post, it can help.